# Dynamic content in custom mobiscroll

Tags: javascript, arrays, mobiscroll

I am using mobiscroll for my select forms and am having no problem when using static content, but...

Now I am trying to create an mobiscroll with dynamic content from ajax/json.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){

        var all_friends = [];

        $.getJSON('http://mypage.com/json/friends.php', function(data){

            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                all_friends.push("'1':'<div class='friend'><div class='profileimg'><img src='http://mypage.com/"+val.img+"'/></div><span>"+val.name+"</span></div>'");
            });

            var friendlist = {all_friends}; // THIS IS WHAT GIVES ME TROUBLE. I CANT DO THIS? //

            var wheel = [{}];
            wheel[0]['Choose friend'] = friendlist;

            $('#friends').scroller({
                display: 'bottom',
                mode: 'scroller',
                wheels: wheel,
                theme: 'ios',
                animate: 'fade',
                cancelText: 'Regret',
                setText: 'OK',
                height: 40,
                width: 280,
                formatResult: function(data){
                    return data;
                },
                onSelect: function(textValue, inst){
                    var returnData = textValue.toString();
                    var returnData = returnData.split(',');

                    var friend = returnData[0];

                    $('#friends').html(friend);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The all_friends array returns:

```
'1':'<div class="friend"><div class="profileimg"><img src="http://mypage.com/someimage.png"/></div><span>Friend1</span></div>',
               '2':'<div class="friend"><div class="profileimg"><img src="http://mypage.com/someimage.png"/></div><span>Friend2</span></div>',
               '3':'<div class="friend"><div class="profileimg"><img src="http://mypage.com/someimage.png"/></div><span>Friend3</span></div>'
```

I don't seem to be able to get the array inside the {} brackets in friendlist? Here is how it should look when it is static:

```
var friendlist = {'1':'<div class="friend"><div class="profileimg"><img src="http://mypage.com/someimage.png"/></div><span>Friend1</span></div>',
               '2':'<div class="friend"><div class="profileimg"><img src="http://mypage.com/someimage.png"/></div><span>Friend2</span></div>',
               '3':'<div class="friend"><div class="profileimg"><img src="http://mypage.com/someimage.png"/></div><span>Friend3</span></div>'}
```

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Please check in the Firebug console if the request to `friends.php` is actually sent. If so - check the responce it returns. Add that to the ticket description

Comment: I have added the return from friends.php in initial question.

Comment: thanks. Now I've got your point. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```
var friendlist = {}

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
   $.extend(friendist, {"1":"<div class='friend'><div class='profileimg'><img src='http://mypage.com/"+val.img+"'/></div><span>"+val.name+"</span></div>'"});
});

// here friendlist will be of the format you expect
```